# Issue with RGB color issue in open3D

Tags: python, numpy, open3d

I am using Open3D library in python. Along with the XYZ coordinates, there are RGB values associated with it. My code is able to recognize the RGB values, when it is either 255 or 0, any value between 1 and 254, the code is not recognizing and the dots have no associated color.

```
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == "__main__":

data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\OneDrive-2019-12-06\\3D TUNNEL SCAN.txt", sep="\t", header=None)


data.columns = ["X", "Y", "Z", "R", "G", "B"]

X = data["X"].to_numpy()
Y = data["Y"].to_numpy()
Z = data["Z"].to_numpy()
R = data["R"].to_numpy()
G = data["G"].to_numpy()
B = data["B"].to_numpy()

rgb = np.asarray([R,G,B])
rgb_t = np.transpose(rgb)
print()
print(rgb_t)
xyz = np.asarray([X,Y,Z])
xyz_t = np.transpose(xyz)
print(xyz_t)


pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd = o3d.PointCloud.colors()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(xyz_t)
pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(rgb_t)
o3d.io.write_point_cloud("C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\open_3d\\Open3D-master\\examples\\TestData\\3D_scanned_data.ply", pcd)

pcd_2 = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\open_3d\\Open3D-master\\examples\\TestData\\3D_scanned_data.ply")

o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd_2],window_name="Tunnel", width=700,height=700,left=50,top=50)
```

Answer (score 6):

Open3D assumes the PointCloud's color values are of **float type** and **in range [0, 1]** as stated in the [doc](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.PointCloud.html#open3d.geometry.PointCloud.colors).

Change your code to:
`pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(rgb_t.astype(np.float) / 255.0)`